# How can I get element from map array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, map-function

I'm facing an issue in ReactJS. How should I get the value from appointments data eg `start_date` and staff data `full_name`

rest api data

```
"appointments": [
{
"id": "10",
"staff_id": "1",
"start_date": "2020-05-12 10:30:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-12 11:00:00",
}
],
"staff": [
{
"id": "2",
"full_name": "Barbershop"
}
]
```

my component

```
   this.state = { 
      appointmentdata:[],
   }

 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments/`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      const appointmentdata = res.data;
      console.log(appointmentdata);
      this.setState({ appointmentdata});
    })
    }

//how i should get the value of staff array fullname
             {this.state.appointmentdata.staff.map(({ full_name }, i) => (
          <div className="full-block">
              <p key={i}>
              {full_name}   //full_name  it is not working
              </p></div>
          )
          )}
```

what should i do?
anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have an error on the console by any chance like `staff` is not an array or it's `undefined` and `.map()` cannot be called on that? If yes, then `null` check will solve the issue with `&&`.

Comment: That rest API data isn't complete JSON; I assume it's wrapped by curly braces? One problem might be that you're supposed to initialize `appointmentdata` to `{ appointments: [], staff: [] }` Like this it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m5vu23jb/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map before actually using it. To create the map take the `staff` array and an object map, assuming the `id` of staff array corresponds to appointment id.

```
var staffMap = staff.reduce((res, item) => { res[item.id] = item; return res; }
```

Now you can use the staff map in the render function.

```
this.state.appointments.map(appointment => {
   return <div> {appointment.start_data} {staffMap[appointment.id].full_name} </div>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `this.state.appointmentdata` to check if appointmentdata is not undefined.
You can also use `id` for key value, because (I guess) it's unique key in DB. Then you can remove `i` from parametes.

```
{this.state.appointmentdata && this.state.appointmentdata.staff.map(({ id, full_name }) => (
  <div className="full-block">
      <p key={id}>
        {full_name}
      </p>
  </div>
))}
```